# How to add a custom icon to a feature in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

When I deploying solution I need to create folder and place the icon there. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use modules for that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453137.aspx

After adding a module to your Visual Studio Project and adding the image inside it, you can reference it that way:

```
var web = SPContext.Current.Web; //web scope, if site scope then use SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb instead.
var myFile = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ModuleName/image.jpg"
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not what I'm looking for

Comment: What are you looking to do then? You can put it in Layout, just create a mapped folder. Here's a guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231521.aspx